# Ideas or existing tools to differentiate color of log4net calls and other actions in methods?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, log4net, readability

Logging doesn't add much readability or use to method code, if I could color code all logging calls like

```
log.ErrorFormat("Expected 10, got:{0}", count);
```

or

```
log.Info("began parsing");
```

into grayed strings for example, method readability would instantly rise I think (I am working in Visual Stuido 2010).

Is there any existing way or project that can do that? If not how would one implement that the easiest way. Im thinking there probably might be some resharper plugin that does that?

if someone can find a better title for this question please feel free to edit

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio allows custom Syntax Highlighting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041%28VS.80%29.aspx

This should allow you to highlight any line that has log.Info for example.